# Decoding text using a random generated substitution cipher

Tags: c++, encryption, random, decode

I am almost done with a program for a random cipher which encodes and decodes. However, I can't get my program to also decode messages. It confuses me as I don't have a key to the cipher, since the letters are replaced in a random manner each time, so I have no idea how a decryption code should look like for this program. What approach should I take?

Here is the code:

```
void randomizer()       //cipher
{
    srand(time(0));     //seed for rand()
    static char alphabet[]="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; //static array to hold uppercase Latin letters
    static char alphabetlow[]="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"; //lower-case Latin letters
    const int LENGTH=sizeof(alphabet)-1;     //length of the array

    int r;
    char temp;
    char tempb;
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<LENGTH; i++)   //loop which shuffles the array
    {
        r=rand() % LENGTH;  //generate a sequnce of pseudo-random numbers

        temp=alphabet[i];          //temp gets the int values of the array elements
        alphabet[i] = alphabet[r];  //randomized letters are copied into the ordered alphabet (now scrambled)
        alphabet[r]=temp;   //ordered letters are copied into the scrambled alphabet

        tempb=alphabetlow[i];   //shuffle second array
        alphabetlow[i]=alphabetlow[r];
        alphabetlow[r]=tempb;
    }
    string text, textb;
    getline(cin,text);

    for (unsigned int i=0; i<text.length(); i++)     //loop to encrypt
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]))   //encrypt only input text which is Latin letters
        {
            if (islower(text[i]))   //checks if input text is lowercase letters
            {
                text[i]=alphabetlow[text[i] - 'a']; //scrambles lowercase letters
            }
            else
            {
                text[i]=alphabet[text[i] - 'A'];    //scrambles uppercase letters
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<"Encrypted: "<<text<<endl;

    getline (cin, textc);
    for (unsigned i=0; i<textc.length(); i++)
    {
        //supposedly code to decode should be here
    }
    cout<<"Decrypted: "<<textc;
```

Comment: If you don't have the key, try statistical analysis. It worked at Bletchley Park.

Comment: Do you know the encoding for the encrypted text or are you going to try to code break it?

Comment: The encoding is done randomly- each letter in the alphabet is substituted by another letter in a random manner. The cipher is based on  the pseudo-random numbers generator.